# Inverse autofilter array of strings

Tags: excel, vba, filter, reverse, autofilter

I have an array of strings, and i need to filter my data where the value in column 8 **does not equal** any of the array values in order to delete entire rows,
i'm using the following line of code to filter the data i want to keep, and it's working fine:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=arrSubmitters, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

and i have the following line to delete entire visible rows which is also working fine:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A2", ActiveSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
```

i need a way to reverse the filter so i can delete visible rows, or a way to delete invisible rows,

knowing that, the unwanted values in column 8 are dynamic so it's complicated to use them to filter,
and that i have also tried preceding the array values with the not equal operator "<>" but did not work as they're more than 2

Comment: Why not delete the hidden.rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the visible range to below the filtered rows and then delete all the rows above.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RevFilter()

    Dim arrSubmitters, lastrow As Long, lastcol As Long
    arrSubmitters = Array("H3", "H11", "H20", "H22")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
        lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=arrSubmitters, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .Range("A1").Resize(lastrow, lastcol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy .Range("A" & lastrow + 1)
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        .Range("A1").AutoFilter
        .Rows("2:" & lastrow + 1).Delete ' include copied header
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```